# Multiple @fopen Not Working CI

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a function in my model in codeigniter which gets a template of the database and so when I fill out my form and click my submit button it will save the write the inputs to the database.php file in codeigniter.

I am having trouble getting two @fopen to work. When I add one more location a clears all the data in the file I am trying to write to.

```
public function load_app_ins() {
$template = file_get_contents(APPPATH . 'modules/install/config/database.php');

$replace = array(
'HOSTNAME' => $this->input->post('hostname'),
'USERNAME' => $this->input->post('username'),
'PASSWORD' => $this->input->post('password'),
'DATABASE' => $this->input->post('database'),
'DBDRIVER' => $this->input->post('dbdriver'),
'DBPREFIX' => $this->input->post('dbprefix')
);    

$template = str_replace(array_keys($replace), $replace, $template);

// Trying To Get Main Directory APPLICATION Not Load Clears Data Should Load 
$file = @fopen(dirname(FCPATH) . '/application/config/database.php', 'w+'); 

// This Location Works OK From Install Directory
$file = @fopen(APPPATH . 'config/database.php', 'w+');

if ($file !== false) {           
$response = @fwrite($file, $template);
fclose($file);
if ($response) {
return true;
} else {
echo 'Error when process'; die;
}
}
```

Comment: The new file overwrites the first one. Try to give the second one a different name or use   file_put_contents(APPPATH . 'modules/install/config/database.php', $template); after you finish with the first file

Comment: the database.php has to remain the same for codeigniter

Comment: ok. the point is that you are overwriting your template variable every time you load the file. you have to find a way around it. BTW try using "a" inteas of "w+" if you just want to add data to the file; http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

Comment: Yes just have to copy the function and rename it but thought i could do it in one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read more on the codeigniter user guide and found there way easier. write_file is much better now.

```
unset($this->db);

$dsn = $this->input->post('db_driver').$this->input->post('db_username').':'. $this->input->post('db_password').'@'.$this->input->post('db_hostname').'/'.$this->input->post('db_database');

if (is_resource($this->db->conn_id) OR is_object($this->db->conn_id)) {

$data = array();
$data['db_hostname']    = $this->input->post('db_hostname');
$data['db_username']    = $this->input->post('db_username');
$data['db_password']    = $this->input->post('db_password');
$data['db_database']    = $this->input->post('db_database');
$data['db_driver']  = $this->input->post('db_driver');
$data['db_prefix']  = $this->input->post('db_prefix');

$get_template_file_contents  = $this->load->view('template/configuration/database.php', $data, true);
write_file(APPPATH . 'config/database.php', $get_template_file_contents, 'r+');
write_file(dirname(FCPATH) . '/admin/application/config/database.php', $get_template_file_contents, 'r+');
write_file(dirname(FCPATH) . '/catalog/application/config/database.php', $get_template_file_contents, 'r+');

redirect('setup/step_4');
}
```